# Select from a table values that have at least one row matching different requirements

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a table designed like this:

```
VALUES table
id INT
id_product_lists INT
id_parameters INT
text_value VARCHAR(50)
number_value FLOAT
```

And I would like to write a query that has two conditions:

```
SELECT id_product_lists FROM values WHERE 
  (id_parameters = 5 AND text_value = "foo") AND 
  (id_parameters = 10 AND number_value > 20)
```

What I want to find is one "product list" which matches two (or more) conditions with different parameters and values.

The query I have so far doesn't work, but at least helps illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.

To clarify, I need to find any `id_product_list` values that have a row that satisfies `id_paramters = 5 AND text_value = 'foo'` and also has a row that satisfies `id_parameters = 10 AND number_value > 20`.

Consider the following sample data:

```
| id_product_list | id_paramaters | text_value | number_value |
+-----------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
|       1         |       5       |    foo     |       1      |
|       1         |       10      |    hey     |       30     |
|       2         |       5       |    foo     |       1      |
|       2         |       10      |    hey     |       10     |
```

id_product_list 1 should be included because it matches both conditions, but id_product_list 2 does not so it should not be returned.

Comment: Use OR , not AND. Then GROUP BY id_product_lists HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_parameters) = 2

Comment: @jpw: But I need to get `id_product_lists` which matches BOTH conditions. From what you are suggesting, I would get product list which matches EITHER of two conditions, but not BOTH.

Comment: @Frodik I believe I understand your question, which I have given my best answer to, but I think in a situation like this it would be *very* helpful to include some sample data and expected results to show others what you're looking for.

Comment: @Frodik if I did understand properly, I gave some edits to your question. Please verify that they are correct, and if not remove them or adjust them accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery for this. You can write your query to pull rows that meet the `id_parameters = 5 AND text_value = 'foo'` requirement like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_product_lists
FROM values
WHERE id_parameters = 5 AND text_value = 'foo';
```

Then, you can use the `IN` operator to only pull id_product_lists that *also* meet the `id_parameters = 10 AND number_value > 20` requirement, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_product_lists
FROM values
WHERE (id_parameters = 5 AND text_value = 'foo') AND id_product_lists IN(
   SELECT DISTINCT id_product_lists
   FROM values
   WHERE (id_parameters = 10 AND number_value > 20));
```

Comment: Thanks. This would work. However, as I have stated in my question, these conditions can be two OR MORE. I am afraid that using your answer and having multiple conditions would be very slow and inefficient. Do you think you could optimize it ?

Comment: @Frodik I'm not quite sure how it could be optimized, but I can tinker with it. Did you see my edit with the `DISTINCT` keyword? Also, while of course I can admit that I'm not perfect, I would suggest executing the query and seeing how long it takes, it may not need to be changed at all.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to search for both id_parameters 5 as well as 10 and hence would not find any result.

Try self join something like:

```
SELECT t1.id_product_list
FROM mytable t1 INNER JOIN mytable t2
ON   t1.id_product_list = t2.id_product_list
WHERE t1.id_parameter = 5 AND t1.text_value = 'foo'
AND   t2.id_parameter = 10 AND t2.number_value > 20
```

Comment: Thanks for effort, but this is not what I am looking for. Because using your query, I would also get false positive results, for example: row having id_parameters=5 and number_value > 20 would also match, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Have you tried this query and saw such a result? See the second query.

Comment: Sorry, that won't work, because I need to get `id_product_lists` which meets *BOTH* the conditions. Using your second query I would get `id_product_lists` which matches EITHER of them.